# Failed to Deploy to Heroku: npm ERR! Error: version not found: 1.1.49 : npm/1.1.49

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

So I'm trying to build a Node.js app ([Hastebin](https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server)) to Heroku but it's failing:

```
Counting objects: 33, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 61.60 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Reading application state
remote:        package.json...
remote:        build directory...
remote:        cache directory...
remote:        environment variables...
remote:
remote:        Node engine:         0.8.10
remote:        Npm engine:          1.1.49
remote:        Start mechanism:     Procfile
remote:        node_modules source: package.json
remote:        node_modules cached: false
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        Downloading and installing node 0.8.10...
remote:        Downloading and installing npm 1.1.49 (replacing version 1.1.62)...
remote:        npm ERR! Error: version not found: 1.1.49 : npm/1.1.49
remote:        npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:259:14)
remote:        npm ERR!     at Request.init.self.callback (/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:120:22)
remote:        npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
remote:        npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:648:16)
remote:        npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
remote:        npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.Request.start.self.req.self.httpModule.request.buffer (/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:610:14)
remote:        npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
remote:        npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
remote:        npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
remote:        npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData (http.js:1366:20)
remote:        npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
remote:        npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
remote:        npm ERR! or email it to:
remote:        npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
remote:        npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_08856eedd22bd2c0d60af50d4929a3ee/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--quiet" "-g" "npm@1.1.49"
remote:        npm ERR! cwd /app
remote:        npm ERR! node -v v0.8.10
remote:        npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.62
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
remote:        npm ERR! not ok code 0
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        You can also try reverting to our legacy Node.js buildpack:
remote:        heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v63
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to tuxbin.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/tuxbin.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/tuxbin.git'
```

By the looks of things it seems there's an issue with the version of npm. Is there a specific version of npm I should be using?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us your code directly in the question please?

Answer (score 0):

> remote:        Node engine:         0.8.10
>   remote:        Npm engine:          1.1.49

These are very old versions of both node and npm. You may want to bump the versions in package.json to something like 0.10.38 (and just leaving npm off to use the default, bundled version)?